# Forcing http or https using a route or other method?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a standard site

www.example.com which has all the public pages

But after user signs in, all in pages are in secure mode: https://www.example.com

I want to force that the relevant pages are only ***http*** or ***https***

From the ***http*** point of view, I don't want https://www.example.com/about/ working as ***Google*** will penalize the site for duplicate content.

And from a logged in point of view I don't want

http://www.example.com/signin/

working for obvious security reasons.

Whats the best way of going about this?

Access to the wrong version should cause a ***permenant 301 redirect***.

Comment: You never know your luck Dave :)

Comment: Luck and award are both appreciated, Dale! PS, which MVC framework are you using? I wanted to re-tag your Post with the Version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I threw this action filter together as an idea of what can be done

```
public class RequireNonSSLAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
       if (filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(RequireHttpsAttribute), true).Length > 0) return;
       if (filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(RequireHttpsAttribute), true).Length > 0) return;
       if (!filterContext.IsChildAction)  return;

        // else

        UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(Request.Url); 

        //change the scheme 
        uriBuilder.Scheme = "http"; 
        uriBuilder.Port = 80; 

        filterContext.Result = this.RedirectPermanent(uriBuilder.Uri.AbsoluteUri); 


     base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }   
}
```

The idea is simply to re-write the url if SSL is NOT requested but used. I'm not in a position to test it at the moment.

Comment: I really like the idea of using a custom attribute for it, the only issue is that it needs to be a RedirectPermanent. And RequireHttps would have to be extended to use a 301 redirect like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624659/shouldnt-requirehttps-in-mvc-do-a-301-permanent-redirect-why-does-it-do-a-30

Comment: @ThomasStiegler use `filterContext.Result = this.RedirectPermanent(uriBuilder.Uri.AbsoluteUri); `

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [RequireHttps] attribute above the Action methods you need to use only Https. If that restrict you in some way you can create a custom attribute.

Comment: I think you miss the point. Once you use `RequireHttps`, all pages used hence foward will use ssl. You have not shown OP a way to remove SSL encyption from pages hit afterward.

Comment: Yes I really missed that, thanks. I'll share an update in my answer tomorrow that include both of the cases.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following. The `RevertToHttpAttribute` is specifically what you asked for, while `OptionalHttp` and `RemoteRequireHttpsAttribute` allow for exceptions, which allows for conflicting attributes to resolve themselves.

I think I will also integrate the IsChildAction line from [Dave A's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21918973/1152054) answer as that simplified things as well.

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents an attribute that attempts a secured HTTPS request to be re-sent over HTTP.
/// </summary>
public class RevertToHttpAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        // abort if it's not a secure connection
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsSecureConnection) return;

        // abort if it's not a GET request - we don't want to be redirecting on a form post
        if (!String.Equals(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod, "GET", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) return;

        var attributes = new[] { typeof(RequireHttpsAttribute), typeof(OptionalHttpsAttribute) };

        foreach (var attribute in attributes)
        {
            // abort if attribute is applied to controller or action
            if (filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(attribute, true)) return;
            if (filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(attribute, true)) return;
        }

        // redirect to HTTP
        string url = "http://" + filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host + filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl;
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(url);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Only requires HTTPS when not running locally
/// </summary>
public class RemoteRequireHttpsAttribute : RequireHttpsAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
        if (filterContext.HttpContext != null && filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsLocal)
            return;
        if (filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(OptionalHttpsAttribute), true))
            return;

        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Represents an attribute that prevents an HTTP/HTTPS request to be re-sent over it's cohort.
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class OptionalHttpsAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

Comment: +1 this solution works well. The reason I chose an action filter is because you also have the option to register it globally. Since action filters always execute after authentication filters, the context would always know whether or not user intends to use SSL.

Answer (score 0):

Two very simple solutions to suggest:

1. Use HTTPS whether or not the user is logged in.

or

1. Have a www.whatever.com subdomain for the public site, and secure.whatever.com for the logged-in user site.  Google does not equate sub-domains, so will not view your content as duplicated.

Comment: this would work and save the trouble of creating the logic to go in and out of secure mode. But dealing with subdomains has it's own headaches; if you're using web-api from the sub-domain you will have cross origin issues, maintaining subdomain routes, etc