# OWIN in ASP.NET - Force HTTPS redirection in website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ssl, https, owin

I wonder if it's suitable to force HTTPS redirection for an whole website in a OWIN module? How can this be implemented?

Currently I'm using the globally registered filter named "RequireSSLAttribute" which is built-in in the ASP.NET MVC framework.

I'm not happy with this standard functionality since it's only able to do temporary redirections and not permanent redirections which is better from an SEO perspective. I have found information that permanent redirections is included in MVC6.

Are there any pros/cons with implementing HTTPS redirection in a OWIN module instead of using the "RequireSSLAttribute" filter in ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Why not just use a custom filter such as [here](http://benjii.me/2015/10/redirect-to-https-asp-net-mvc/) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624659/shouldnt-requirehttps-in-mvc-do-a-301-permanent-redirect-why-does-it-do-a-30)? Unclear why you would want to use an OWIN module for this, rather than doing the same thing Microsoft did.

Comment: Thats actually one of my questions above, but just to come with an possible pro, the HTTPS redirection will probably be performed at a earlier stage when using OWIN middleware?

Comment: If you want it to happen at an early stage (and don't need it to be conditional), then perhaps a better solution would be to use the [IIS Rewrite Module](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2013/05/22/http-to-https-redirects-on-iis-7-x-and-higher/) to do it, before ASP.NET is even involved, and can easily be switched off in your dev environment. But then, it all depends on how you want to host your application.

Comment: @NightOwl888 Because by the time filters are asked, Owin openid will have already redirected to the authentication server with the wrong return url. That's one reason anyway.